# Несанкционированное удаление содержимого файла - aiofiles (асинхронная работа с Json)

Tags: python, json, asyncio

**Код:**

```py
import json
import typing as t

import ramda
import aiofiles


async def update(file_name: str, keys: list, new_value: t.Any) -> None:
    async with aiofiles.open(f"{file_name}.json", "r") as file:
        data = await file.read()

    async with aiofiles.open(f"{file_name}.json", "w") as file:
        await file.write(
            json.dumps(
                ramda.assoc_path(keys, new_value, json.loads(data)),
                indent=4
            )
        )
```

Для того чтобы объяснить проблему, поэтапно покажу что происходит.

1. Необходимо прочитать содержимое файла и сохранить в переменную `data`.

```json
{
    "key": "value",
    "key2": "value2",
    "ke3": "value3"
}
```

2. Дальше, полученный словарь в виде строки `'{"key": "value"}'` преобразуется в словарь.

```py
json.loads(data)  # -> {'key': 'value'}
```

3. Изменение значения на новое.

```py
ramda.assoc_path(keys, new_value, json.loads(data))  # new_value допустим заменяется на True
```

4. Преобразование в формат для записи в файл.

```py
json.dumps(
    ramda.assoc_path(keys, new_value, json.loads(data)),
    indent=4
)  # -> '{\n    "key": true\n}'
```

Содержимое файла обнуляется, он просто становится пустым. Из-за этого выдаёт ошибку `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` в строке с **ramda.assoc_path()** + перед тем как эта ошибка вылезает, в блоке кода где читается файл возвращается пустая строка.

Всё это происходит спонтанно. То есть, это решение может работать без перебоев несколько минут, но потом внезапно плюнуть ошибкой и удалить содержимое.

Comment: Не знаю что такое `ramda`, но в целом чтобы не было такого сценария, что файл просто пропал, обычно сначала пишут в новый, временный файл, и только убедившись, что всё успешно записалось, удаляют старый файл, а новый переименовывают в старый. Ну и ещё тут вы всё-равно `json` пишете сначала в строку, можно писать его во временную переменную до того, как вы файл на запись открыли, в этом случае опять же старый файл сохранился бы, потому что код упал бы ещё до записи в файл.

Comment: `ramda` просто облегчает изменение значения в словаре на произвольной глубине. А что касается файла, то почему-то сбрасывается его содержимое. До использования асинхронного чтения/записи всё было в порядке, правда модуль json самостоятельно писал всё в файл.

Comment: 1) Начните с нормального `json` файла 2) Преобразуйте прочитанный файл в `json` заранее и сохраняйте в отдельную переменную, печатайте её 3) Сохраните то, что возвращает `ramda`, в переменную, напечатайте её, прежде чем выводить её в файл. 4) Запустите ваш код, посмотрите, что выведется на печать, проверьте получившийся файл 5) Если всё ок - повторите процесс. Когда всё сломается - предоставьте сюда всю печать и содержимое файлов, которые получались в процессе. А может вы и сами догадаетесь, где будет засада.

Comment: Все описанные действия я несколько раз повторял и в вопросе написал что кто возвращает.

Comment: Я понимаю, что в теории должно быть. Я вам объясняю, как на практике ошибку найти.

Comment: Как обойти то? Я все данные возможные предоставил. Всё что вы сказали, уже проделывалось.

Comment: А вы обрабатываете где-нибудь исключения, которые теоретически может выкинуть функция update? Вдруг где-то выкидывается исключение, а вы его не обрабатываете и поэтому не знаете об этом, например

Comment: Не должно ничего блокироваться. Удаление происходит спонтанно весьма, иногда удаляет, а иногда работает нормально.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил эту проблему не решая её. Перенёс всю работу в **SQLite**. Хотя с этой ошибкой при работе с файлами до сих пор непонятно.

**Теперь (получение значение)**:

- Значение в ключевой колонке (и некоторые другие дополнительные данные) передаются модулю для работы с базой данных;
- Если имя колонки совпадает с именем той, где храниться **Json** (в данный момент в качестве строки), значение парсится и преобразуется в словарь, возможно как-то изменяясь.

Обновление информации по тому же принципу.

Скорее всего, в **SQLite** есть встроенные возможности для работы с **Json**, про это ещё почитаю и если что перепишу, пока что так.

**UPD:**

Поскольку асинхронность требуется чтобы работать с данными использующимися в процессе работы Discord бота, соответственно ничего не блокируя, я буду использовать **MongoDB**, а **Json** для хранения настроек. Я думаю так надёжней.